# Basic list operations using python

Tags: python, list, function

These three functions are apart of my study guide and would greatly appreciate some assistance.
In each case, the function returns a value (so use the return statement): it does not print the value (no print statement) or mutate (change the value of) any of its arguments.

1) The repl function takes three arguments:
◦old is any value;
◦new is any value;
◦xs is a list.

```
 Example:
 >>> repl('zebra', 'donkey', ['mule', 'horse', 'zebra', 'sheep', 'zebra'])
 ['mule', 'horse', 'donkey', 'sheep', 'donkey']
```

It returns a new list formed by replacing every occurrence of old in xs with new.

It must not mutate the list xs; i.e., after return from the function, the actual argument given for xs must be what it was before.

```
 >>> friends = ['jules', 'james', 'janet', 'jerry']
 >>> repl('james', 'henry', friends)
 ['jules', 'henry', 'janet', 'jerry']
 >>> friends
 ['jules', 'james', 'janet', 'jerry']
```

2) The search function looks for a value in a list. It takes two arguments:
◦y is the value being searched for.
◦xs is the list being searched in.

It returns the index of the first occurrence of y in xs, if it occurs; −1 otherwise.

```
 Examples:
 >>> words = ['four', 'very', 'black', 'sheep']
 >>> search('four', words)
 0
 >>> search('sheep', words)
 3
 >>> search('horse', words)
 -1
```

3) The doubles function is given a list of numbers and returns a new list containing the doubles of every number in the given list.

```
 Example:
 >>> doubles([1, 3, 7, 10])
 [2, 6, 14, 20]
```

It must not mutate the given list:

```
 >>> salaries = [5000, 7500, 15000]
 >>> doubles(salaries)
 [10000, 15000, 30000]
 >>> salaries
 [5000, 7500, 15000]
```

This is to be done without using any list methods except append. (In particular, you may not use the index or count for the search function.)

Although you can use the list len function, and the list operations +, *, indexing, slicing, and == for comparing lists or elements. You will need to use some of these but not all.

Any help is greatly appreciated like I mentioned in the introduction.

So far all I have is.

```
 def repl (find, replacement, s):
     newString = ''
     for c in s:
         if c != find:
             newString = newString + c
         else:
             newString = newString + replacement
     return newString

 def search(y, xs):
      n = len(xs)
      for i in range(n):
          if xs[i] == y:
              return i
      return -1
```

and....

```
 def search(key,my_list):
   if key in my_list:
     return my_list.index(key)
   else:
     return
```

I'm not sure what needs to be returned after the else statement.

Comment: I am not getting the right answers as shown in the examples. Also the code for the last two problems I still have yet to compile. I'm trying to refresh my memory with this and have had some trouble remembering the correct solutions.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the details you've added here? You'll have a better chance to find the right answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def relp(old,new,my_list):
  final = []
  for x in my_list:
    if x is old:
      final.append(new)
    else:
      final.append(x)
  return final


def search(key,my_list):
  if key in my_list:
      return my_list.index(key)
  else:
      return -1

def doubles(my_list):
  return[x*x for x in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this lesson is about list comprehensions

```
doubles = lambda my_list: [x*2 for x in my_list]
repl = lambda old_t,new_t,my_list: [x if x != old_t else new_t for x in my_list]

print repl("cow","mouse",["cow","rat","monkey","elephant","cow"])
print doubles([1,2,3,4,'d'])
```